# need to learning asp.net web services, where to start?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am back to the job market next month. I am looking for an asp.net developer job.  my current job does not use web service at all.  last time, I am using it was 6,7 yrs ago.

If I need to pick it up, where to start.  I searched on amazon.com, those .net web service books are really old, they were written in 2002.  Does that mean web service is outdated, no one using it? is there a newer tech to replace it?

I did see a few newer books, but they are RESTful web service, whats the difference between web servie and RESTful web service.

please let me know what you are currently using and where should I start learning.

Comment: stack overflow is not google. A web servie is where you use spider webs to make a silk smoothie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned web services by just tinkering around and looking at code examples.

Here are a few resources to get you started. If you have more questions, feel free. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231/ASP-NET-Web-Service

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

Comment: thank you so much. those are great resources. I was hoping to find a good book. Do you know any?

Comment: Unfortunately not off the top of my head. I might be a junior .NET programmer, but I don't remember ever touching a .NET book, haha! You could try at your local book store.

Answer (score 1):

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) is the successor to web services. WCF contains a lot of [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734662) they are ways how you bind clients and server. You can use [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) if you need compatibility with clients that used ASP.NET Web services (ASMX-based services).

And now about books. I have found [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997) very useful. But it doesn't contain full information about security.

[image]